# Upload image use intervention package laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, intervention

I select 3 images to upload. Once image crop with 3 size [1903 x 793, 960 x 600, 446 x 446]. But image upload success not full 9 images.

Please help me!

My code:

jQuery:

```
$("#inputImage").change(function () {
                var files = this.files,
                    formData = new FormData();
                if (!files.length) {
                    return;
                }
                formData.append('_token', $('input[name=_token]').val());
                formData.append('category', 'category');
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    formData.append('images[]', files[i]);
                }
                console.log(formData);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{{ route('images.upload') }}',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result)
                    }
                });
            });
```

UploadController:

```
    public $sizeCrop = array(array('width' => '1903', 'height' => '793'), array('width' => ' 960', 'height' => '600'), array('width' => '446', 'height' => '446'));

public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $files = $request->file('images');
    $category = $request->get('category');

    $destinationPath = storage_path('app/public/images/' . ((isset($category)) ? $category : ''));
    if (!is_dir($destinationPath)) {
        Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('images/' . ((isset($category)) ? $category : ''));
    }

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());

        foreach($this->sizeCrop as $key => $size) {
            $filename = (time() + $key) . '_' . $size['width'] . '_' . $size['height'] . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img->crop($size['width'], $size['height'])->save($destinationPath . '/' . $filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your upload data is not too big, so that it crosses PHP post data limit!

Comment: I change _upload_max_filesize_ and  _post_max_size_ to 40M in file php.ini but it not working well

Comment: What do you mean by "But image upload success not full 9 images." Is there an error message ? Could you send it ?

Comment: Upload is success, don't have error message. But number of image save in folder not full 9 images